# Can I use one mobx store in two different components in react-native app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, store, mobx, mobx-react

I have a module with topTabNavigator that wrapped with mobx provider with the store:

```
export class ModuleTeam extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <TopTabNavigator />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

And inside of topTabNavigator I have two screens:

```
export class TopTabNavigator extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name='Team' component={ScreenTeam}/>
        <Tab.Screen name='Invites' component={ScreenInvites}/>
      </Tab.Navigator>
    )
  }
}
```

Can you tell me please is it a good way to share the store between two screens and inject it like this, separate in every component:

```
@inject('store')
@observer
export class ScreenTeam extends Component {

}
```

```
@inject('store')
@observer
export class ScreenInvites extends Component {

}
```

I know is it a good practise to divide one store on a few, but in my case there is some data that uses on the both screens, and I don't want repeat myself.

Comment: i can't understand what do you expect.
may be you need some like that: `@inject('AuthStore', 'TeamsStore')`, `@inject('AuthStore', 'InvitesStore')`

Comment: Can i make different stores for the different components and inject it?

Comment: added answer above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create different stores, several. example how to do it

```js
const App = () =>
  <Provider FirstStore={FirstStore} SecondStore={SecondStore}>
     <app stuff... />
  </Provider>
```

```js
const Button = (({ FirstStore, SecondStore, label, onClick }) =>
  <button style={{
      color: FirstStore.colors.foreground,
      backgroundColor: SecondStore.colors.background
    }}
    onClick={onClick}
  >{label}</button>
));

export default inject("FirstStore", "SecondStore")(observer(Button));
```

or some advanced example

```
class stores {
  this.ModalsStore = new ModalsStore(this);
  this.AuthStore = new AuthStore(this);
  ...
}
```

```js
const mobxStores = stores();

const App = () =>
  <Provider {...mobxStores}>
     <app stuff... />
  </Provider>
```